# Can Delete/Insert sometimes be better than Update for database records?

Tags: database

I have a webpage where people create an order for pipe.

The orders are stored in the following tables:

- ORDER for the shipping/customer info.
- REQUESTED_PIECE that can contain many records per order.
- ASSIGNMENT that can also contain many records per order.
- CUT that can contain many records per ASSIGNMENT

When you go to edit one of these, all of this information is put on a single page for editing.

When the user clicks Finish it seems to me that the only way handle this is to Delete all records for the old order and reinsert the new stuff. Something about deleting and reinserting seems like it would be bad practice to me so I would like to know if I am missing something.

Comment: Have you tried "updating" the tables? Deleting records usually isn't good business practice, i.e. what happens if the delete succeeds and the insert fails?

Comment: I think the only reason you would want to delete and insert a new record is to give that order a new auto-incremented number.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;
```

Be careful when updating records. If we had omitted the WHERE clause (or made a mistake in it), you could update all the records in the table instead of the ones you wanted to update.

One reason you might want to delete and insert a new record is to give that record a new primary key (if it is auto-incrementing).  You should be careful about doing this, as it would mess up any foreign keys in other tables that use this primary key

Comment: But when all the data that is being edited is on the same page in one big form (for multiple tables) how do you keep track of when to update/insert/delete based on what the user changed.

Comment: @Mike Please give more details regarding your tables, the data they contain, and how they relate to each other.  I don't see how your current implementation: "it seems to me that the only way handle this is to Delete all records for the old order and reinsert the new stuff" addresses "how do you keep track...".

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem in my website, my solution was getting the ID of the table when i populate the fields in a hidden input or in the session variable, so when something change, i only update my DB by giving the stored ID. hope it helps.